# Trying to Delete Message from List with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes

So I have a simple list of messages that users can submit. I'm trying to put a delete button (that works) for each message. But as you can see [here](https://project-dylanaj5.c9.io/) you get an error about an entirely different action if you click the button. I'm not totally sure about where I went wrong. My guess is that I'm out of my depth in the controller area. Here are all the applicable files.

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root 'messages#index', as: :home
 get '/new' => 'messages#new', as: :edit
 resources :messages
 post '/new' => 'messages#create', as: :create
 delete 'messages/:id' => 'messages#destroy', as: :delete
```

The relevant controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @messages=Message.all
    end
    def new
        @messages=Message.new
    end
    def destroy
        @messages=Message.find(params[:id])
        @messages.destroy
    end
    def create
        @messages = Message.new(message_params) 
            if @messages.save 
            redirect_to '/' 
                else 
            render 'new' 
            end
    end
    private
    def message_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:content, :subject)
    end

end
```

The Relevant View:

```
<div class="main">
    <div="messages">
        <%@messages.each do |t|%>
        <h2 class="subject"><%=t.subject%></h2>
        <p class="content"><%=t.content%></p>
        <%=link_to "Delete Message", delete_path(t)%>
        <% end %>
        <%=link_to "Create Message", edit_path%>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your link is just a normal link which performs a HTTP `GET`. You'll need to read up on HTTP methods and Rails.

Comment: delete 'messages/:id' => 'messages#destroy', as: :delete  change this to -  get 'messages/:id' => 'messages#destroy',

Comment: Changing it to delete 'messages/:id...etcetc does not change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the method `DELETE` as well, otherwise it will perform the simply `GET` request. Here's how:

```
<%=link_to "Delete Message", delete_path(t), :method => 'delete' %>
```

Remember if you do not mention any `method` in `link_to`, the default will be taken as `GET`. So you have to be explicit about other HTTP methods.

**Edit:**

Either use `resources :messages`, or use the routes that you wrote yourself. Using `resources :messages` is a bit easier, and it is the preferred way.

Using `resources :messages`, you'd have to write:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Message", t, :method => 'delete' %>
```

**Edit 2:**

You are getting the error `Template is missing`, because in your `destroy` method, neither you are `render`ing anything, nor you are `redirect_to`ing anything. After you `destroy` the object, you will have to tell where should it go. Like if you want the user to go all messages page after he/she `destroy`s the record, you need to add the following line to the end of the method:

```
redirect_to messages_path
```

Comment: I did this, I now get a much larger error, from external source.

Comment: Ok, Actually! This works but when I click the button I get an error, but if I go back and reload the page, the message is gone.

Comment: You have written `resources :messages`, and you are generating the routes yourself as well. Why? `resources :messages` will generate all CURD routes for you.

Comment: Ok, but what is the reason for 'Template is missing' error. I get the error, but If i go back and reload the message is gone.

Comment: Ok, I worked it out, I had to append redirect_to '/' into the destroy action because I didn't have an embedded ruby template. But your answer is still valid.

Comment: @DylanMcGrath I've updated my answer. And if you think, this is the valid answer, and it helped you, you can accept it.